# AWS facial rekognition within an Android app

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio, face-recognition, amazon-rekognition, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I'am trying to make an **Android application** which can send images taken by a camera on an Android tablet to AWS Rekognition. It's the intention that pictures will be directly send to the **AWS Rekognition** service **without** the need of an **S3 bucket**. The picture itself don't need to be saved in the cloud. Only the face metadata need to be stored on AWS in a collection. Afterwards the ultimate goal is for a person to be able to capture his face again, and AWS says there is a match with a previous face in the collection.

There is a lot of information on the internet. But most of the times AWS suggest the Amplify framework. And I don't really know if this is necessary in such simple case.

I have already done all the steps in the AWS CLI (and these work) but I don't succeed to do these steps into Android studio. Below I describe the steps that I have done in the AWS CLI. I would do these steps in Android Studio, but I'm not a pro in programming this language.
(I have already made a collection within the AWS CLI.)

First I index a face which can be found by AWS into a picture. In my AWS CLI code I use S3 as an example. It should be the intention that I can send the picture directly to AWS Rekognition. This action only need to be done if someone specially push a button. So taking a picture and sending it to AWS Rekognition to **index** the **face** in a specific collection.

```
aws rekognition index-faces --image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"bucketName","Name":"picture1.jpg"}}' --collection-id "collectionName" --max-faces 1 --quality-filter "AUTO" --detection-attributes "DEFAULT" --external-image-id "picture1.jpg"
```

Then when a user push another button it need to take a picture again and it need to be send to AWS Rekognition to **search** the **collection by the image** which was sent. I have already succeeded this with the following AWS CLI code. It should also be the intention to send the picture directly to AWS without the need of S3. AWS returns a match with a face which is already in the collection.

```
aws rekognition search-faces-by-image --image '{"S3Object":{"Bucket":"bucketName","Name":"picture.jpg"}}' --collection-id "collectionName"
```

Again I'am not a professional in Android studio, so it would be very nice if someone haves a quite easy solution. It would also be very nice if someone can tell me if the Amplify framework is really necessary.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use Amplify, you can use Rekognition through the [AWS Java SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/rekognition/AmazonRekognition.html).

To achieve this same functionality you're getting with the CLI, you can first index the face(s) in the collection using [IndexFacesRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/rekognition/model/IndexFacesRequest.html), or you can forego this and create the collection manually over the CLI if this is a one-time operation.

To search the collection's faces by *image*, you would simply need to modify the following code snippet to pass in a byte-64 encoded image instead of the S3 URL. Full documentation for the `searchFacesByImage()` method [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/rekognition/AmazonRekognition.html).

```java
AmazonRekognition client = AmazonRekognitionClientBuilder.standard().build();
SearchFacesByImageRequest request = new SearchFacesByImageRequest().withCollectionId("myphotos")
        .withImage(new Image().withS3Object(new S3Object().withBucket("mybucket").withName("myphoto"))).withMaxFaces(5).withFaceMatchThreshold(95f);
SearchFacesByImageResult response = client.searchFacesByImage(request);
```

Comment: Can you send a proper link where i can see all functionality of code?